# Set default permissions within directory to use stickybit

Tags: permissions

Essentially, I want to set the permissions of a directory to prevent the deletion of files unless you are the owner, however allow all users within the directories group to modify files.  However, I want these permissions to carry over to any created subdirectories.

I am aware that you can do this with an existing directory and all of it's subdirectories using the stickybit, ie:

```
chmod -R /path/to/base/dir 1775
```

If you create another directory 'otherdir' within /path/to/base/dir it does not contain the sticky bit.

I'm also somewhat aware of using setfacl to modify the default file permissions for created files, however I can't find anything on setting the stickybit (or something with similar functionality) using setfacl.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This belongs at unix.stackexchange.com. But I'm pretty sure the answer is that it can't be done.

Comment: Should I repost it there or will it get moved automatically?  Also do you know of any alternatives for something like this?

Comment: The way this is usually handled in `/tmp` is that when user-specific subdirectories are created, only the owner is given write permission. Only the main `/tmp` directory needs to be world-writable, so that's where the sticky bit is needed.

Comment: It's generally up to the application that creates the subdirectories to set the permissions correctly for it.